# Blogger comments disappear after switching to custom URL

Tags: blogger

I recently switched to a custom URL instead of a *.blogspot.com URL, but now all the comments from my posts are gone. How can I get them back?

**Update**: I've been waiting several <strike>days</strike> weeks and they haven't shown up yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly which of these caused it to work, but recently I made several changes:

- I [transferred the blog ownership](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4205/how-can-i-change-the-google-account-associated-with-blogger/4208#4208) from a Gmail account to a Google Apps Account on the same domain.
- Instead of forwarding the naked subdomain with a CNAME record to `ghs.google.com`, I switched it to use a 301 redirect from the naked subdomain to `www`.
- I added MX records to the naked subdomain and started using Google Apps Mail.

... and then suddenly all my comments appeared again. It has been about 3 weeks since they first disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait. I have heard of this happening before. It just takes some time for everything to update. So just wait a few hours and they should be back.

Comment: I saw people saying that too... sorry, I should have specified that I've already waited several days.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a known problem, there are dozens and more requests of help in **Blogger** support forum.

There is an **[official discussion](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/blogger/thread?tid=3548049c2f79e7fb&hl=en)** to check for updates and submit info for help.

Comment: That link you posted is for people that see a discrepancy between the comment count it shows and the amount of comments they actually have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this (I'm just making this up, so don't trust it too much):

- Switch back to your blogger domain name (http://username.blogspot.com)
- Go to the "Basic" settings page and export your blog
- Now switch to your new domain name (http://www.yourdomainname.com)
- Go back to the "Basic" settings page and import your blog

It's worth a shot, I suppose!  Good luck!

Comment: That sounds dangerous! It's supposed to work without doing something like this. I'm not sure how, but it now works (without having to do the steps you posted). Good out-of-the-box thinking though.