# How can I change the Google Account associated with Blogger?

Tags: blogger, account-management

I already had a Blogger account which I have been using for the past year. The problem is that I just created a new email account/Google Account that I want to use instead of the old one I have been using.

Is there any way to transfer my blog over to this new account? If not, what are my other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new blogger account for your new Google account and transfer your blog by:

- Going to **Settings** -> **Permissions** -> **Blog authors** and inviting your new account.
- Accepting the invitation.
- Clicking **grant admin privilages** next to the new author in your original account.
- Clicking **remove** next to your original account.

Comment: Google's official instructions: http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41448

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Once the author is added, there are no options (like to promote them to admin).

Answer (score 2):

Simon Brown's answer is correct, although you're well advised to clear your cache in between each step to remove any chance of removing yourself when the new account hasn't actually been given any rights.

But there's more:   some components which may be part of a blog (eg pictures, videos, calendars, feedburner-feeds, etc)  are owned separately from the blog.   You need to transfer them (where possible) or make migration plans for ones for which the onwership cannot be changed.

I've written an article with more detail about this (can't be bothered typing the same thing over and over again) but don't think I'm allowed to post a reference here, but you can find links to in on the Blogger help forum.

Update:   you can find it [here](http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2010/01/transferring-blog-ownership.html).

Comment: sure you can link to it. If it doesn't let you, type the URL and I'll create the link for you.